# Spring Boot With MongoDB Causing IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am building application which uses `spring-boot` version 1.2.1.RELEASE, `spring-security`, `spring-data-mongodb`, and `hibernate-validator`.

I have the following `Document`

```
@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "username is required")
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty(message = "password is required")
    private String password;

    @Email(regexp = ".+@.+\\..+", message = "email address is invalid")
    private String email;

    public User() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Its repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    User findOneByUsernameIgnoreCase(String username);
}
```

The service

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public User authenticate(String username) {
        return repository.findOneByUsernameIgnoreCase(username);
    }
}
```

Custom UserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = service.authenticate(username);

        if (user == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("invalid username"); }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                username, user.getPassword(),
                commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER")
        );
    }
}
```

and finally assigning UserServiceDetails

```
    @Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }
    }
```

Upon starting up the application the following error occurs

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not     initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6022f5dd: startup date [Mon Mar 02 17:32:08 SGT 2015]; root of context     hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 135 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.    AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6022f5dd: startup date [Mon Mar 02 17:32:08 SGT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:181)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:177)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 145 more
```

I understand that it is caused by UserRepository but I can't figure out the cause of it.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed by upgrading to spring boot 1.2.2.RELEASE.